# Hide subcomponent vaadin-text-field from Component vaadin-date-picker

Tags: javascript, css, vaadin, shadow-dom

I'm new to Vaadin and trying to create an instance that hides the `vaadin-text-field` from the component `vaadin-date-picker`.

I started out by reading the documentation for `vaadin-date-picker` about the shadow DOM property stated [here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-picker/html-api/elements/Vaadin.DatePickerElement).

I tried with "Scoping Styles in a Theme Module" but the whole thing including the calendar icon disappeared.

Current code as below,

```
render() {
    return html`
    <dom-module id="trim-inputbox" theme-for="vaadin-date-picker">
      <template>
        <style>
          :host(.special_field) [part="text-field"] {
          visibility:hidden;
          }
        </style>
      </template>
    </dom-module>
    <vaadin-date-picker class="special_field"></vaadin-date-picker>
    `;
}
```

Thanks so much again for any kind help.

Comment: Do you want only the calendar icon?

Comment: @a1626, yea I am actually also trying now.

Comment: @a1626, later I want the text-field only also inside same html therefore I asked like this.

Comment: Maybe `text-field` from styling should be solution to your problem.

Comment: @a1626, sorry donot really understand your solution.

Comment: try styling [part="text-field"] https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin#readme

Comment: @a1626, I run into trouble here. If I set  [part="text-field"] {visibility:hidden} then whole thing disappear (including calendar icon). I guess it is because both text-input-filed and calendar are wrapped inside there. I will try another approach and see how to eliminate only a single sub-component. Thanks for help! Plan to working on this again tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, i had a feeling that'll happen. I doubt there's way. You can fork there component i you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed already a calendar icon is part of a text-field itself. 
[image]

In [Styling section](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-picker/html-examples/date-picker-styling-demos) there is an example of using `<vaadin-date-picker-light>`:

```css
<style>
   .my-input2 input {
     border: none;
     font-size: 14px;
     background: none;
   }
</style>
```

```java
<vaadin-date-picker-light>
  <div class="my-input2">
    <iron-icon icon="event"></iron-icon>
      CHECK-IN:
       <iron-input>
         <input size="10">
       </iron-input>
    </div>
 </vaadin-date-picker-light>
```

Maybe you could use this instead?

Comment: I will try tmr.